# How do I lock a warp into place in illustrator once applied?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects, warp

So I created an arch but every time I rotate it it will become distorted.

I tried using shift+cntrl+E but that just said I was applying another effect to it.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

When you have an object with a warp envelope selected, in the bar along the top, you can switch between *Edit Envelope*, and *Edit Contents* to either rotate the object including the warp effect or rotate the object before the warp effect is applied.

[image]

Alternatively you can perform *Object > Expand Appearance* to "bake in" the effect and alter the original object. The downside is that you can't go back later and change the warp.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem in Illustrator CC 2023.  What version are you using?  An object with a warp effect rotates as expected. I haven't updated to the most recent 2024 version yet.